# A case of normal force working in the “wrong direction”

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

Consider a painter on a scaffold pulling themself up by two ropes connected to the ends of the scaffold via a set of pulleys. The painter has mass $M$, the scaffold has mass $m$, and the painter pulls themself up with a force $F$ on each rope. Say the painter rises with uniform acceleration $a$.

Modeling this situation, one arrives at the system of linear equations
$$
2F - N - mg = ma
$$
$$2F + N - Mg = Ma$$
(for example in [this video](https://youtu.be/4-eDnJMcaMc)), where $N$ is the normal force of the scaffold on the painter. Solving this system of equations, we find:
$$
N = \frac{2F(M-m)}{M+m}
$$
But this seems very strange to me: this means that $N$ is negative if the scaffold has more mass than the painter. If I’m interpreting this correctly, that would mean the normal force of the scaffold on the painter is working *downward*, i.e., the scaffold is somehow pulling the painter down. Intuitively, that doesn’t seem possible. Am I interpreting this correctly? Or is the appropriate response to treat the term $M-m$ as $\max\{0, M-m\}$ instead (i.e., no normal force if the scaffold is too massive)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By assuming that the acceleration of the painter and the scaffold are both equal to $a$, you are implicitly assuming that the painter and the scaffold are connected together e.g. the painter has tied or glued or nailed themselves to the scaffold. In this case $N$ *can* be negative, and indeed $N$ will be negative if

$M - m < 0
\\ \Rightarrow M < m$

i.e. if the scaffold has a greater mass than the painter.

However, if the painter and the scaffold are *not* connected together then you are right, $N$ cannot be negative. In this case, if $M < m$ then we have to drop the assumption that the accelerations of the painter and the scaffold are the same. So if $M < m$ we set $N$ to $0$, and the accelerations of the painter and the scaffold to $A$ and $a$, and we have

$2F -mg = ma \\ 2F - Mg = MA$

which we can rearrange to find

$\displaystyle a = \frac {2F} m - g
\\ \displaystyle A = \frac {2F} M - g$

and since $M < m$ (and we assume $F >0$) then we find that $A > a$. In other words, if the scaffold has a greater mass than the painter, then by pulling on the rope the painter pulls themselves up *off* the scaffold.